Tracing light through a house of mirrors
Suppose you find yourself in a house of mirrors! You stand in the corner, and you trace how your image reflects off of mirror A, followed by mirror B, followed by mirror C, followed by mirror A.
But you notice something! The mirrors are arranged in just the right way that the the above image (A -> B -> C -> A) lands directly on top of the image that results from the reflections B -> A -> B -> C!
In this code-golf challenge you will be given a sequence of mirror reflections, and a rule about how the mirrors interact with each other, and you will output the minimal sequence of reflections that produce a given image.
Inputs
Your program should take two inputs. Both inputs can be given in any reasonable format.
First input
The first input is a list of "reflections" consisting of \$n\$ different symbols, such as 12121333212132121.
Second input
The second input specifies the way the mirrors are related to each other via "braid relations" between the \$n\$ symbols, and will be specified something like this, where all unordered pairs of distinct integers will be assigned an integer greater than 1:
{(1,2) => 5, (2,3) => 3, (1,3) => 2}.

The (1,2) => 5 means that \$12121 = 21212\$, which is to say a length five "braid" of \$1\$s and \$2\$s can be swapped.
The (2,3) => 3 means that \$232 = 323\$, which is to say a length three "braid" of \$2\$s and \$3\$s can be swapped.
The (1,3) => 2 means that \$13 = 31\$, which is to say a length two "braid" of \$1\$s and \$3\$s can be swapped.

Because the mirror image of a mirror image is the same as the original image, we say that two reflections by the same mirror "cancel": \$11 = 22 = 33 = 44 = \varepsilon\$, where \$\varepsilon\$ denotes the empty string "".
Output
Your program should output the earliest such word that results in the same image as the input. Earliest first means that it both the shortest possible word that agrees, but also that it is the alphabetically earliest of all such shortest words.
Example
If you were given the following word and braid relations

Input 1: 12121333212132121
Input 2: {(1,2) => 5, (2,3) => 3, (1,3) => 2}

Then we might do the following sequence of rewrites to get the earliest word:
$$\begin{align}
&1~2~1~2~1~\underbrace{3~3}_{=\varepsilon}~3~2~1~2~1~3~2~1~2~1
\\
=~&1~2~1~2~1~3~2~1~2~\underbrace{1~3}_{=31}~2~1~2~1
\\
=~&1~2~1~2~1~3~2~1~2~3~\underbrace{12121}_{=21212}
\\
=~&1~2~1~2~1~3~2~1~\underbrace{2~3~2}_{=323}~1~2~1~2
\\
=~&1~2~1~2~1~3~2~\underbrace{1~3}_{=31}~2~3~1~2~1~2
\\
=~&1~2~1~2~1~\underbrace{3~2~3}_{=232}~1~2~3~1~2~1~2
\\
=~&\underbrace{12121}_{=21212}~2~3~2~1~2~3~1~2~1~2
\\
=~&2~1~2~1~\underbrace{2~2}_{=\varepsilon}~3~2~1~2~3~1~2~1~2
\\
=~&2~1~2~1~3~2~1~2~\underbrace{3~1}_{=13}~2~1~2
\\
=~&2~1~2~1~3~2~1~2~1~3~2~1~2
\end{align}
$$
So given the above inputs, your program should output 2121321213212.
Test data
 - Input 1: `"ababab"`
 - Input 2: `{(a,b) => 3}`
 - Target output: `""`

 - Input 1: `"cbababab"`
 - Input 2: `{(a,b) => 4, (a,c) => 2, (b,c) => 3}`
 - Target output: `"ac"`

 - Input 1: `2123212`
 - Input 2: `{(1,2) => 3, (1,3) => 2, (2,3) => 3}`
 - Target output: `12321`

 - Input 1: `"acbababa"`
 - Input 2: `{(a,b) => 4, (a,c) => 2, (b,c) => 3}`
 - Target output: `"cb"`

 - Input 1: `"acbababa"`
 - Input 2: `{(a,b) => 7, (a,c) => 2, (b,c) => 3}`
 - Target output: `"acbababa"`


Note: This is secretly a code-golf challenge about Coxeter groups.

May I assume the unordered pair in the mapping is unique? Or will there be any testcases that {(1,2) => 3, (1, 2) => 5}; 21212121?

Why test case 2 not output cb? acbababa=acbbabaa=acab=caab=cb

@tsh Never mind, I somehow completely missed the "shortest" part. You're right.

@tsh My program actually thinks cbababab=cababbab=cabaab=cabb=ca=ac, or have I done something wrong?

Is cancelling one-way?

@Neil i agree, my guess is that the 4 was supposed to be a 7 (in which case the answer is indeed what is given). tsh's comment has the reduced version of the given target output under the reduction rules as given

@l4m2 Without duplicate pairs (as my first comment shown), I find that padding extra letter pairs do not optimize the result. But with duplicate pairs, padding extra letter is become funny

@tsh From the link, {(1,2) => 3, (1, 2) => 5} would be just inputted {(1,2) => 1}

@tsh—you can assume that the unordered pair in the mapping is unique.
Also, you have exactly the right idea about the test data; I got some wires crossed in my draft. I've added a test case to reflect what you're talking about.

@Neil, I had a mistake in the draft, and you found right output from the given input. The example is fixed now.

@I4m2, you can solve the problem treating it as one way, but it's a non-obvious mathematical fact that this is the case.

05AB1E, 40 bytes
ε`∍ÐÙÂ‡‚}Dí«sÙSºõδ‚«U¸ΔDεVXεYs`:}}«˜êé}н

Inputs in reversed order, with the braid relations as a list of \$[string,length]\$-pairs.
Try it online or verify all test cases.
Explanation:
Step 1: Create a list of all possible replacements:
ε          # Map over the (implicit) first input of braid relations:
 `         #  Pop the pair, and push string and length separately
  ∍        #  Extend the string to the specified length
   Ð       #  Triplicate this string
    Ù      #  Uniquify the top copy
     Â     #  Bifurcate it; short for Duplicate & Reverse copy
      ‡    #  Transliterate (e.g. "ababa","ab","ba" becomes "babab")
       ‚   #  Pair the two 'mirrored' strings together
}D         # After the map: duplicate the list of pairs
  í        # Reverse each pair in the copy
   «       # Merge the two lists together
s          # Swap to get the second (implicit) input-string
 Ù         # Uniquify its characters
  S        # Convert the string to a list of characters
   º       # Mirror/double each character in the list
     δ     # Map over each double letter string:
    õ ‚    #  Pair it with an empty string
«          # Merge the two lists together
 U         # Pop and store this list of replacements in variable `X`

Try just this first online (without U).
Step 2: Keep expanding the (sorted) list as long as there are replacements possible:
¸          # Wrap the second (implicit) input-string into a singleton list
 Δ         # Loop until the list no longer changes:
  D        #  Duplicate the current list
   ε       #  Map over each string:
    V      #   Pop and store the current string in variable `Y`
    X      #   Push the list of replacement-pairs `X`
     ε     #   Map over each pair:
      Y    #    Push the current string `Y`
       s   #    Swap so the current replacement-pair is at the top again
        `  #    Pop and push both value in this pair separately
         : #    Do the replacement
     }     #   Close the inner map
   }«      #  After the outer map: merge it to the original list
     ˜     #  Flatten it to a single list of strings
      ê    #  Uniquify and (lexicographically) sort this list
       é   #  Then sort an additional time by length
 }         # Close the changes-loop

Try the first two steps online.
Step 3: Since it's already being sorted correctly in the previous step, its first item is the result we want to output:
н          # Pop and keep just the first/shortest item
           # (which is output implicitly as result)


Ruby, 172 164 157 133 131 128 bytes
->r,*a{(r*a[0].size**9).map{|x,n|x*=n;a.map{a+=[_1.sub(/(.)\1/,'').sub(q=x[0,n],w=x[1,n]),_1.sub(w,q)]}}
a.min_by{[_1.size,_1]}}

It is hard to exaggerate how comically slow this is.
It would use about \$2^{10,000,000}\$ gigabytes of memory
for the smallest test case.
But you can try it here
with some slight modifications so it can run on a sensible machine.
-24 from stealing lots of improvements from tsh's python answer, thanks!
Will update the explanation below when I have time,
but for now it refers to the previous version:
->s,r{a=[s]
(r*s.size**9).map{|x,n|x*=n;a.map{|s|s.sub! /(.)\1/,'';a+=s.gsub(/#{x[0...n]+?|+x[1..n]}/).map{$`+$&.tr(x[1..2],x)+$'}}}
a.min_by{|s|[s.size,s]}}

The general idea is to initialize an array containing just the input,
then repeatedly apply all* possible transformations
to all elements of the array,
and append the new results.
If it takes \$n\$ transformations to get to the fully reduced form,
then as long as we have done this at least \$n\$ times,
the array will contain the answer somewhere,
and we can take the min_by length (tiebreaking alphabetically) to get it.
Of course,
since we never throw away the previous results,
every single string we have ever seen gets processed again
on each iteration.
This means the size of the array grows exponentially,
which makes this solution totally impractical for any nontrivial input.
But that's okay,
this is code golf.
The first line (initialize the array)
and the last line (take the winner)
are self-explanatory --
the meat of the solution is line 2.
Let's start with the regex:
x*=n; [...] /#{x[0...n]+?|+x[1..n]}/

x is the two characters in a braid and n is the reducible braid length.
We build this pattern
(by modifying x in place!)
that matches any possible substring of the two characters in x
that can be transformed.
Note that if there is a braid longer than the corresponding relation,
there are several overlapping matches,
but we only get some.
This is fine, though:
making the first substitution yields an adjacent pair of same symbols,
which after removal has the net effect of shortening the braid
until it is at most as long as the corresponding relation.
.gsub( - ).map{$`+$&.tr(x[1..2],x)+$'}

This is a pretty neat bit of Ruby flair.
We call gsub,
the global regex replace function,
on that regex,
but decline to give a replacement.
This makes gsub instead return an enumerator over each match.
We ignore the value of the enumerator
and instead refer to some magic globals:
$` is the string before the match,
$& is the match,
and $' is the string after the match.
So we map over each match,
and for each one return the original string
with the matched substring replaced with $&.tr(x[1..2],x),
swapping the relevant characters.
x used to be two characters,
but x[1..2] now exists because we modified x in place in the previous step,
which is delightfully gross.
a.map{|s|s.sub! /(.)\1/,'';a+=s.gsub - }

The main body of the loop first deletes a single adjacent pair, if any,
in each string.
We unfortunately have to do this outside the gsub
because the input might be something like aabc with no relevant relations,
where the only thing to do is delete the aa
(and all the gsub.maps return an empty array).
Obviously,
this is worse than writing s.gsub! instead,
to delete all adjacent pairs instead of only one.
But that's okay,
this is code golf.
(r*s.size**9).map{|x,n| - }

Finally,
we do that whole thing \$|s|^9\$ times.
Why?
Well,
we need an upper bound on how many steps it might take to reduce.
I'm pretty sure \$|s|^2\$ is actually such a bound:
there can be at most \$|s|\$ deletion steps,
and between each deletion step
there can be at most \$|s|-1\$ useful braid-swapping steps
(because a step is only useful if it brings the two symbols involved in the next deletion closer together).
I put a 9 instead of a 2 just to be safe.
Naturally,
this makes the runtime even more hilariously impractical.
But that's okay,
this is code golf.

But that's okay, this is code golf. Love that you've added this after multiple paragraphs. :D

" It would use about 2^10000000
gigabytes of memory for the smallest test case."
... but it works; that's the spirit. Not your problem no one specified memory limitations.

Python 3, 156 bytes
f=lambda r,*a:f(r,*T)if{*a}^(T:={k.replace(x[:n]or y,x[1:n+1])for k in a for y,n in r+[(c+c,0)for c in k]for x in[y*n,y[1]+y*n]})else min(sorted(T),key=len)

Try it online!
-16 bytes by Jonathan Allan

{*a}!=(...) -> {*a}^(...) saves one.

three more with ...k.replace(*t)for k in a for t in[... TIO

With some extra branching and the addition of some redundant paths we can get rid of t saving another five bytes TIO - you may even find more saves from there :)

...yep six more bytes from there TIO

Charcoal, 101 bytes
≔⦃⦄ζＦＥη…κ⊕ι«≔⮌Φ⮌ιλε§≔ζΦιλε§≔ζε✂ι¹»⊞υθＦυＦζＦＥ⌕Ａι§ζκ⁺⁺…ιλκ✂ι⁺λＬκＬι¹«ＷΦλ№λ×²ν≔⁻λ×²⌊μλ¿¬№υλ⊞υλ»⌊Φυ⁼Ｌι⌊ＥυＬλ

Attempt This Online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:
≔⦃⦄ζＦＥη…κ⊕ι«≔⮌Φ⮌ιλε§≔ζΦιλε§≔ζε✂ι¹»

Expand the braid relations into a bidirectional mapping between substrings e.g. "bc": 3 becomes "bcb": "cbc", "cbc": "bcb".
⊞υθＦυ

Start a breadth-first search of sequences of reflections.
Ｆζ

Loop over each mapping.
ＦＥ⌕Ａι§ζκ⁺⁺…ιλκ✂ι⁺λＬκＬι¹«

Loop over all the possible reflections from this mapping.
ＷΦλ№λ×²ν≔⁻λ×²⌊μλ

Remove all reflection pairs.
¿¬№υλ⊞υλ

If this is a new result then add it to the search list.
»⌊Φυ⁼Ｌι⌊ＥυＬλ

Output the minimum result of minimal length.

JavaScript (ES8), 131 bytes
-3 bytes and a bug fixed thanks to @l4m2
Expects (array)(string), where array is of the form [ [ "x","y",n ], ... ]. Returns a string.
The symbols used are non-zero decimal digits.
a=>m=g=s=>a.map(g[s]=([x,y,n])=>(h=(p,q)=>g[S=s.replace(p,[q])]?S>+m?0:m=S:g(S))(/(.)\1/)&h(x=x.padEnd(n,y+x),y+=x/10|0)&h(y,x))&&m

Try it online!
Commented
a =>                // outer function taking the array a[]
m =                 // m = best answer so far, initially NaN'ish
g = s =>            // g is a recursive function taking the string s
a.map(g[s] =        // eventually mark g[s] as encountered
([x, y, n]) =>      // for each triplet (x, y, n) in a[]:
  ( h = (p, q) =>   //   h is a helper function taking (p, q):
    g[              //     test g[S] ...
      S = s.replace //     ... where S is obtained by replacing in s
        (p, [q])    //     the first occurrence of p with q
    ] ?             //     if g[S] is defined:
      S > +m ?      //       if S is greater than m (as integers):
        0           //         do nothing
      :             //       else:
        m = S       //         update m to S
    :               //     else:
      g(S)          //       do a recursive call with S
  )(/(.)\1/) &      //   invoke h to remove a doubled symbol
  h(                //   invoke h to replace:
    x = x.padEnd    //     the string "xyxy.." of length n (n>1)
      (n, y + x),   //
    y += x / 10 | 0 //     with the string "yxyx.." of length n
  ) &               //
  h(y, x)           //   invoke h to replace "yxyx.." with "xyxy.."
)                   // end of map()
&& m                // return the final answer


Fail 22,[], Requiring input contain no /(.)\1/ doesn't help as 9ε9 always exist

and direct regex there works

Python3, 341 bytes
R=range
def f(a,b):
 q,s,S=[a],[],[a]
 for A in q:
  s+=[A]
  for j,k in b:
   u,U,T='','',[]
   for i in R(k):u+=j[i%2];U+=j[j[i%2]==j[0]]
   for i in R(len(A)-1):
    if A[i]==A[i+1]:T+=[A[:i]+A[i+2:]]
    if(V:=A[i:i+len(u)])in[u,U]:T+=[A[:i]+[u,U][V==u]+A[i+len(u):]]
   for i in T:
    if i not in S:q+=[i];S+=[i]
 return min(s,key=len)

Try it online!
